# Gas Vent Pipe - Outside Placement

Tags: furnace, pipe, vent, exhaust

I Recently adjusted the exterior furnace gas vent pipe as per the picture below.  The old placement ended where the first elbow (up/left looking at the pic) is currently.  However given that my 2 year old son likes to play close to the garage door, the vent smoke was contently blowing in our face.

I purchased a couple of elbows and a few feet of pipe and extended it around and up.

**Is this safe to do?**

Is there a maximum length that the pipe needs to be?

My concern it extends too high and there may be CO coming back to the house.  I have had it this way for a week, and have a CO detector in the furnace room with a 0 read.

Any advice would be appreciated because the last thing I want to do is put my family at harms way.

[image]

Comment: Does the furnace have a blower to exhaust the gas?

Comment: Since you seem to have an answer to your question, please say "thank you" properly by clicking the "up" arrow next to _all_ the answers that helped you, and the check-mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_. That's the way we do things 'round here.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility, but it's not very high.

The current vent is near the soffits, but the risk there is fairly minimal. It looks to be 1-2 feet from the pipe so there's some diffusing that will happen. It's also possible the warm exhaust will rise far enough to clear the soffit before it can reach it.

Even if the exhaust reaches the attic, your attic is designed to let the air flow freely inside, which would further diffuse it. It's unlikely any part of your attic is open to the interior. Even if you have, say, an attic door, we're talking minute traces that could actually get through it. In the winter (when you would be running the furnace) the heat from your house would be trying to get into the attic as well.

Regardless, it's always a good idea to have a carbon monoxide detector in your house. If something goes wrong with the furnace attachment to the exhaust, that could pose a far worse hazard.

Comment: Yes it does, it’s a high efficiency furnace.  

Thanks for the response and appreciate the feedback.  Yes, I see how close it is to the soffit.  The garage is completely separate from the home so this soffit leads to the garage attic, so I am not too concerned with that.

Answer (score 0):

There won’t be any issues or not enough air flow or the furnace will shutdown.

The problem would be more with the restrictions caused with the 90’s this will cause more “possible” problems than the length.

I would suggest to rotate the 90 at the top at a 45 away from the house so the fumes don’t get sucked in at the vents in the soffits, I don’t think this will be an issue as it is but it will also direct the slightly acidic moisture away from the structure. Don’t get concerned about the term slightly acidic you can wash your hands with it and it will not harm you but over time it can cause damage or discoloration to paint and make uncoated metal to rust faster.

Other than changing the direction it should be fine as there is a flow and or pressure sensor to make sure the blower s working.

Comment: Hi Ed, thats exactly what I did, changed the direction away from the soffits.  Appreciate the help everyone.

Comment: If an answer is helpful upvote or accept the green check Mark that’s how thanks are given and it helps others find the answer to similar questions it doesn’t cost you and you might get more upvotes on your question.